# roscd finds ros_gazebo_pkgs but rospack find don't

Tags: gazebo, ros-lunar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have installed ROS Lunar in an Ubuntu 16.04.4.

I'm trying to find I package. With roscd I find it, but with rospack find don't.

```
user@MyPC:~$ roscd gazebo_ros_pkgs
user@MyPC:/opt/ros/lunar/share/gazebo_ros_pkgs$ rospack find gazebo_ros_pkgs
[rospack] Error: package 'gazebo_ros_pkgs' not found
```

I have tried with roscpp, and both find it:

```
user@MyPC:~$ roscd roscpp
user@MyPC:/opt/ros/lunar/share/roscpp$ rospack find roscpp
/opt/ros/lunar/share/roscpp
```

Is gazebo_ros_pkgs not installed properly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296649/roscd-finds-ros_gazebo_pkgs-but-rospack-find-don%27t/) by [Elric](https://answers.ros.org/users/30817/elric/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2018-07-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think that the METAPACKAGE can be found with ROSCD but the rospack doesn't
i tried with the navigation METAPACKAGE , the result is the same.

---

Originally posted by [C3MX](https://answers.ros.org/users/25486/c3mx/) with karma: 150 on 2018-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0